# In-app tutorial

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

Im looking at adding a tutorial kind of thing to my app. Basically I want to be able to give a quick message across of what the parts in the app do. I want the users to see it once and not again. I have searched relentlessly for this but I always found app building tutorials.

A lot of games have what I want but I cannot for the life of me find how to do it or, what it is called to find a tutorial. Could someone please help me out.

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: Just a [quick search](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tutorial) at [CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) shows several possible pre-made solutions, like [this one](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/eaintroview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to build it yourself.

What I usually do is, on top of the view i want to explain, add a semi transparent view with some arrows pointing at stuff and a small text/button explaining it. All of that has to be modal and you can save in the NSUserDefaults if the user has already seen it/skipped it/launched the app for the first time. You'd have a method that builds all those views and you simply call it in viewDidLoad (by checking against a simple  boolean value store in those previously mentioned NSUserDefaults, for example)